# Does matrix transform the $X$-$Y$ space of the vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Does matrix transform the $X$-$Y$ space of the vector, so it's not that the output of calculations is the vector with other data in the same basis vector space?

Let's consider the matrix:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 3  \\ 
    10 & 1  
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
 multiplied by a vector $(a,b)$ to get $(8,13)$.

Does it change the basis for output or we just get the new output vector in the same basis?

Comment: You're going to have to be more precise in formulating your question to get an answer

Comment: True. Have edited it :)

Comment: What is "the X-Y space of the vector"?

Comment: e1 hat = [1,0] , e2 hat = [0,1]

Comment: No operation _ever_ changes the space it operates upon (though some produce values in another space). A mapping $V\to V$ is called a transformation of $V$, but it really just sends each vector of$~V$ to another (or maybe the same) vector of $V$; the space itself doesn't budge.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that's exactly what I've been confused about.

Comment: Just to clarify: if we consider doing shearing, rotation or any kind of matrix tranformation. What exactly does it change if not the space? The basis?

Comment: @maria the elements of the space

Answer (score 0):

Your output vector is expressed in the same basis, so if your basis was
$$
e_1 = (1,0),\qquad e_2=(0,1)
$$
then
$$
(8,13) = 8e_1 + 13 e_2.
$$